# how do filter duplicate object in a array using JavaScript and return with a flag?

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

i have a array of object from there i need to filter duplicate item based on two key on return with extra key on it

```
let word = [
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 5,
    end: 8,
    name: "sam",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 85,
    end: 114,
    name: "Abhishek",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
];
```

in above sample i want to filter out duplicate based on start and end key also need to add a key called haveDuplicate if same object have duplicate it need to be true

```
let filterd = [
  {
    start: 5,
    end: 8,
    name: "sam",
  },
  {
    start: 85,
    end: 114,
    name: "Abhishek",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    haveDuplicate: true,
    name: "alex",
  },
];
```

i tried lodash but i cannot able to add extra key
below is what i tried

```
_.uniqBy(data, obj => obj.start && obj.end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and check if the item exist with `Array.prototype.find()` for that like so:

```js
let word = [
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 5,
    end: 8,
    name: "sam",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 85,
    end: 114,
    name: "Abhishek",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
];

const filteredArr = word.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const obj = acc.find(item => item.start === curr.start && item.end === curr.end);
  if(obj) {
    if(!obj.haveDuplicate) {
      obj.haveDuplicate = true;
    }
    return acc;
  }
  
  acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) 
[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Using `find()` every iteration is not very efficient. Keeping track of what was already seen is far more efficient and doesn't require multiple iterations

Answer (score 0):

You can combine reduce and Object.values

```
Object.values(word.reduce( (a,x) => { if(a[x.start+'-'+x.end]) x = {...x, haveDuplicate: true}; return a[x.start+'-'+x.end]=x,a} ,  {} ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array filter,

you can update the key depending on your use case.

```js
const word = [
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 5,
    end: 8,
    name: "sam",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 85,
    end: 114,
    name: "Abhishek",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
];

const map = {};
const res = word.filter((item) => {
  const key = item.start + "-" + item.end;
  if (!map[key]) {
    map[key] = true;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `_.uniquBy()` you will need a function to return a value from each element that can be used to compare with.

This won't solve how to add the `haveDuplicate` property but is intended to just show how to use that specific method

```js
const concatStartEnd = (o) => `${o.start}|${o.end}`;

console.log(_.uniqBy(word, concatStartEnd))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
let word=[{start:1,end:4,name:"alex"},{start:5,end:8,name:"sam"},{start:1,end:4,name:"alex"},{start:85,end:114,name:"Abhishek"},{start:1,end:4,name:"alex"}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, use `_.groupBy`, and we can read number of items in group to determine if it has duplicate.

```js
let word = [
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 5,
    end: 8,
    name: "sam",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
  {
    start: 85,
    end: 114,
    name: "Abhishek",
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    end: 4,
    name: "alex",
  },
];

const grouped = _.groupBy(word, o => `${o.start}-${o.end}`);

const result = _.map(grouped, occurrences => {
  if (occurrences.length > 1) return { ...occurrences[0], haveDuplicate: true };
  return occurrences[0];
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```